# How can I seal the holes my essentia tubes created?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-thaumcraft, minecraft-direwolf20

I'm in the process of automating essentia delivery to my infusion altar, and I built something that lets me dump crystallized essence into a chest to be converted into essentia and put into warded jars.

[image: Yeah, not the best setup, but it works]

My problem is, I need to seal up the vis tubes, so drops don't fall into the utility room containing the alchemical furnaces and such. I've tried *every* combination of Forge Microblocks and I can't get anything to stick. Covers will work on one side, above the grass, but nothing else seems to do it.

What else can I try to seal that hole? I don't want drops (especially warded jars) going down there.

The redstone just opens valves, which lets me re-crystallize the essentia if I need to (sharing a line down to the crystallizers that the altar uses). I tried to build it so that I could use Ender IO facade instead, it just didn't work out (every way I could think of trying it)

I'm open to other mods that aren't in the current DW20 1.7 pack. I feel like I should be able to do this with microblocks, but neither nook or corner will place.

Specifically, where you see tubes going into the ground, I need some kind of facade or block. But this is a bigger question, suppose you want to put an essentia tube through a wall, and want to seal up around it :)

Comment: Oddly, I can't _get_ a jar to go down there, but essentia tubes _will_ and I need to use golems, hence the worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can add the mod [Witching Gadgets](http://www.curse.com/mc-mods/minecraft/228268-witching-gadgets), a Thaumcraft Addon that will add support for the Forge Multi Parts ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/35hfaw/covers_or_facade_support_for_thaumcraft_essentia/))